# Searching data items in listview

Tags: android, listview, search, adapter

For searching the data item in the `listview` i had done the coding and here is the logic, created the `arraylist`, on `onTextChanged` class the keyword of `edittext` is compared with the `listview` and the result is stored in `arraylist` called `searchResult` and using `lazyadapter` made it to display in `listview`, able to get the search result in `toast` but now i have to tell the lazy adapter to arrange the items of `listview` in order and display it in `listview`, i tried in manyways but nothing helped me to get the result.

here's my full code with `lazyadapter`.

```
public class Home extends ListActivity {
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList;
ListView list;
LazyAdapter adapter;
JSONArray posts;    

 //ArrayList thats going to hold the search results
  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> searchResults;
  LayoutInflater inflater;
// All static variables
static final String URL = "http://www.abc.com/ads/?json=get_recent_posts";  

 static final String KEY_POSTS = "posts";
 static final String KEY_ID = "id";
static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
static final String KEY_CONTENT = "content";
static final String KEY_AUTHOR = "author";
static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
static final String KEY_ATTACHMENTS = "attachments";
static final String KEY_SLUG = "slug";
static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumbnail";
static final String KEY_IMAGES = "images";
static final String KEY_URL = "url";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final EditText searchBox=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);
    final ListView  list=(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    //get the LayoutInflater for inflating the customomView
     //this will be used in the custom adapter
     inflater=(LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


 final  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Creating JSON Parser instance
                final JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

                // getting JSON string from URL
                JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL);
                try {
                     posts = json.getJSONArray(KEY_POSTS);

        // looping through all song nodes <song>
                for(int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject c = posts.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(KEY_ID);
                    String title = c.getString(KEY_TITLE);
                    String date = c.getString(KEY_DATE);
                    String content = c.getString(KEY_CONTENT);
                    // to remove all <P> </p> and <br /> and replace with ""
                     content = content.replace("<br />", "");
                     content = content.replace("<p>", "");
                     content = content.replace("</p>", "");

                    //authornumber is agin  JSON Object
                    JSONObject author = c.getJSONObject(KEY_AUTHOR);
                    String name = author.getString(KEY_NAME);

                    String url = null;
                    String slug = null;
                    try {
                    JSONArray atta = c.getJSONArray("attachments");
                    for(int j = 0; j < atta.length(); j++){
                        JSONObject d = atta.getJSONObject(j);

                        slug = d.getString(KEY_SLUG);

                        JSONObject images = d.getJSONObject(KEY_IMAGES);

                        JSONObject thumbnail = images.getJSONObject(KEY_THUMB_URL);
                        url = thumbnail.getString(KEY_URL);

                    }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }

            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(KEY_ID, id);
            map.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
            map.put(KEY_DATE, date);
            map.put(KEY_NAME, name);
            map.put(KEY_CONTENT, content);
            map.put(KEY_SLUG, slug);
            map.put(KEY_URL, url);
            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            songsList.add(map);
                }   
                }catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                    }               

              //searchResults=OriginalValues initially
                searchResults=new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(songsList);

         // Getting adapter by passing json data ArrayList
            adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, songsList);    
             list.setAdapter(adapter);


             searchBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                 public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                       //get the text in the EditText
                       String searchString=searchBox.getText().toString();
                       int textLength=searchString.length();

                              //clear the initial data set
                       searchResults.clear();

                       for(int i=0;i<songsList.size();i++)
                       {
                      String playerName=songsList.get(i).get("title").toString();

                      if(textLength<=playerName.length()){

                      //compare the String in EditText with Names in the ArrayList
                        if(searchString.equalsIgnoreCase(playerName.substring(0,textLength)))
                              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),playerName,1).show();
                        searchResults.add(songsList.get(i));
                      }
                       }

                       adapter=new LazyAdapter(Home.this, searchResults);
                       list.setAdapter(adapter);
                       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                     }

                     public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                         int after) {


                       }

                       public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


                       }
                      });
                 }
```

**LazyAdapter**

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
  TextView title;
private Activity activity;
 // private TextWatcher textWatcher;
   private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
   private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
   public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

   public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
     activity = a;
    data=d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
}


public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_home, null);

    TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title); // title
    TextView date = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.date); // artist name
    TextView content = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.content);  // duration
    TextView name = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.name); 
    // duration
    ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image); // thumb image

    HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
    song = data.get(position);



    // Setting all values in listview
   title.setText(song.get(Home.KEY_TITLE));
    date.setText(song.get(Home.KEY_DATE));
    content.setText(song.get(Home.KEY_CONTENT));
    name.setText(song.get(Home.KEY_NAME));

   imageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get(Home.KEY_URL), thumb_image);
    return vi;
} 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you miss this line just Add this line in `yourActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);`
here `addTextChangedListener` this

```
 searchBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {           

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int start, int count, int after) {
            // your data    

            Home .this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);                          
        }
```

EDIT: change like this

```
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                   //get the text in the EditText
                   String searchString=searchBox.getText().toString();
                   int textLength=searchString.length();

                          //clear the initial data set
                   searchResults.clear();

                   for(int i=0;i<songsList.size();i++)
                   {
                  String playerName=songsList.get(i).get("title").toString();

                  if(textLength<=playerName.length()){

                  //compare the String in EditText with Names in the ArrayList
                    if(searchString.equalsIgnoreCase(playerName.substring(0,textLength)))
                          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),playerName,1).show();
                    searchResults.add(songsList.get(i));
                  }
                   }

                   adapter=new LazyAdapter(Home.this, searchResults);
                   list.setAdapter(adapter);
                   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

       Home .this.adapter.getFilter().filter(s);    
                 }
```

Comment: if i add this line Home.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(s), m getting error in getFilter() as "The method getFilter() is undefined for the type LazyAdapter". @NagarjunaReddy.P

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use Filter class for searching/Filtering any item from the list.You need to invoke that class from onTextChanged() API of the EditText and the logic to filter the contacts has to be written inside the filter class.
e.g.,

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){   
               //Call filter class
        getFilter().filter(s);

    } 
//getFilter class
 public Filter getFilter() {
                 //put a Null check
        if (null == filter) {
                  //Calling a private filter class, that contains the logic..
            filter  = new FilterList(); 
                }
        return filter; 
    }

private class FilterList extends Filter {
//Here, I was using a pojo to store the attributes of the List Item
        List<DefaultPojo> buffer = new ArrayList<DefaultPojo>();
        @Override
        protected FilterList performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            FilterList results = new FilterList();          

                    if(constraint != null && constraint.toString().length() > 0)
                    {
                       if(List != null){
                        int count = List.size();
                        ArrayList<DefaultPojo> filt = new ArrayList<DefaultPojo>(count);

if(constraint != null && constraint.toString().length() > 0){  
                    //Logic for searching the list
}
                    else{
                        //Load the Parent List....                      
                        buffer = List;

                    }
            //Sorting the obtained List..                   
            Collections.sort(buffer);
            if(buffer!=null && buffer.size()>0){
            results.values = buffer; 
            results.count = buffer.size(); }

            return results;
        }
//Setting the content to the List and Adapter will be done by publishResults() method..
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            filteredList = (List<DefaultPojo>)results.values;
            if(filteredList!=null){     
                ListAdapter = new ListAdapter(Contactlist.this,mFilteredContactDetails);
                List.setAdapter(ListAdapter); 
            }
            else{
                List.setAdapter(null);
                ListAdapter=null;
            }           
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to reinitialize your `adapter` after searching.

You can try like this.

Prepare one more `ArrayList` say `tempList` & on first time initialize it with your `songsList`.Then pass the `tempList` to your adapter at the time of initialization. And on searching, reintialize `tempList` with your `searchResults` & just call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.